# Sending a users actions from one page to another

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

OK, so I have a basic knowledge of PHP, and I'm fairly advanced in CSS/HTML/JavaScript.

I'm trying to set up a page that when an Admin types a message ("Hello, world!"), all the clients automatically update and display this new message in an H1 element.

How do I get the admin page to "talk" to the client page?

I can use PHP, JavaScript and HTML for this, but I'd rather stick to just HTML and JavaScript as my knowledge in PHP is not the best.

Is this possible, and if so, does anyone know how to do this?

It means a lot to me that you guys are willing to help, so thanks!

Comment: For this particular task, you're going to need to use `websockets`. A good example of this would be [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I'll take a look at this.

Comment: Or simple ajax polling might be fine, depends just how instant this needs to be

Comment: @Steve Needs to be very quick; as fast as it can possibly be. What method would be quicker?

Comment: @user2324827 In that case, sockets probably are the answer, as very rapid ajax polling can put quite a lot of load onto the server

Answer (score 3):

We can call this real time notifications too.

I won't teach how to do, but will talk about some solutions and ways to do it.

### The Node.JS

The first solution is use a websocket. The PHP isn't the best programming language to work with websockets. Node.JS is a great solution. You can use http://socket.io/.

With Socket.IO you can work with websockets easily. Doing things like that in some minutes.

I recommend you read the article below:

- http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html

### Paid solutions

A great paid solution is the https://pusher.com/. When you work with notifications, the Pusher won't cost cheap, because you can have thousand of visitors in your website. But when you work with a chat, the Pusher is good.

(the Pusher price is based on the connected users of your website, and not the notifications that were sent, that is a big problem when we work with notifications, for example, a small volume of messages, but so many users receiving)

Have many other solutions, but i think Pusher is one of the bests.

### PHP Solutions

1. Elephant.io: http://elephant.io/, you'll make a integration between Node.JS, PHP and Socket.io.
2. Ratchet: http://socketo.me/, i recommend you read the documentation: http://socketo.me/docs/, really great way to start.

Have many solutions too, but know this 2 above first, they're great.

### The solution with the "pure power" of the olders

A little bit unnecessary with the new technologies, but works.

Make a application that send messages and save into the database, after that, basically make a ajax polling updating the messages every 5 seconds, for example, and showing to the user when loads.

Works well, but will consume much of your server, and will update even if the application has no new messages to show. (You can work better with it and avoid this problem).

Comment: +1 for describing the "old school" technique for companies that still mistrust IE10.....